# ASP.Net MVC 3.0 Razor View Grid Ajax Pagination

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, pagination

How can i implement Ajax for this Grid i have?

```
@{
var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort: "FirstName", rowsPerPage: 5);
}
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml(
 tableStyle: "grid",
 headerStyle: "head",
 alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
 columns: grid.Columns(
 grid.Column("FirstName", "First Name"),
 grid.Column("LastName", "Last Name"),
 grid.Column("Address"),
 grid.Column("DOB"),
 grid.Column("Gender")
 )
    )
</div>
}
```

I tried adding ajaxUpdateContainerId but it is giving some error.
I couldn't understand it.

I have created my grid like below

```
var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 2, defaultSort: "FirstName", canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
grid.Bind(Model, rowCount:Model.Count(), autoSortAndPage: false);
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
```

But it showing all the records in the grid where i want to show only 5 records in grid then paging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great article on the subject here http://www.unboxedsolutions.com/sean/archive/2011/01/23/15964.aspx

```
@using AdventureWorks.Common
@using ThisController = MvcDemo.Controllers.GridExampleController
@model GridExampleViewModel

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Index"; }

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage: ThisController.PageSize, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
    grid.Bind(Model.Employees, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
    @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id="grid" },
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { EmployeeID = item.EmployeeID, ContactID = item.ContactID })),
            grid.Column("FullName"),
            grid.Column("Title")
        ));
}
```

Comment: I have created grid like this var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 2, defaultSort: "FirstName", canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
    grid.Bind(Model, rowCount:Model.Count(), autoSortAndPage: false);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

Comment: It seems your not using the skip and take methods in your model. queryResults.Skip(page * records).Take(records)

Comment: I did some thing like this  grid.Bind(Model.Take(5), rowCount: Model.Count(), autoSortAndPage: false); it lists 5 record out of 50 and when i click page two it will still show the first 5 records only

Comment: Yes it will take 5 records from your table, please do follow the example page I provided you need to add paging to your model.